# How does Advaita answer the Seven-Anuppatti of Ramanujacharya

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, ramanujacharya

What answer is given by Advaitins as reply to Ramanuja's seven-questions over Advaita such as, Aashraya, Tirodhan-Anuppatti, etc.